# Django Rest framework with ajax pagination, how to switch data in the template?

Tags: ajax, django-rest-framework

How can I fill in the table data when switching to the next page using ajax pagination.

views.py

`class PositionPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1
    max_page_size = 5`

```
def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    context = {
        'next': self.get_next_link(),
        'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
        'count': self.page.paginator.count,
        'results': data,
    }
    return Response(context)
```

`class PositionListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Position.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = PositionSerializer
    pagination_class = PositionPageNumberPagination`

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    page = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(self.queryset, many=True)
    return Response({'data': serializer.data})
```

position_list.html

`{% extends 'index.html' %}`
`{% load static %}`
`{% block title %}The list of positions{% endblock %}`
`{% block content %}`
    `

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span>
        <a id="previous">previous</a>
        <a id="next">next</a>
    </span>

    <span id="count"></span>
</div>

<div>
    <button id="add_position">Add</button>
    <button id="edit_position">Edit</button>
    <button id="delete_position">Delete</button>
</div>
```

`{% endblock %}`

`{% block addscript %}`
    `<script src="{% static 'js/positions.js' %}"></script>`
`{% endblock %}`

urls.py

`path('positions/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='positions/position_list.html')),`

position.js

When I click on 'next element', the data does not change, but the API is started (api / positions/?page=2)

`$.ajax({
    url : "/api/positions/",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function (data) {
        let results = data.results;
        let positions = $('.positions');`

```
    for (let i in results){
        positions.append(`<tr id=${results[i].id}><td>${results[i].name}</td></tr>`)
    }

    $('#count').html(data.count);
    $('#previous').attr('href', data.previous);
    $('#next').attr('href', data.next);
    }
```

});